# How to set default QML styles in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, qml

I need to analyze multiple GPX files with QGIS. My workflow so far is as follows:

1. Add an OSM tile layer to serve as a map background.
2. Import the GPX file as a vector layer, select the routes and waypoints layers.
3. Right-click the properties for the routes layer, open properties, select QML style file for lines.
4. Right-click the properties for the waypoints layer, open properties, select QML style file for points.

Is there a way I can set my line and point styles as the default for newly imported GPX vector layers (either globally or within the project)?

The GPX filenames differ, thus filename-related magic is not an option.